# Unable to change android emulator date

Tags: android, appium

I want to change android emulator time to 1 day ahead, is that possible i tried with below solutions, but could not happen.(System ->Mac)

adb -e shell date  $(date "+%Y%m%d.%H%M%S")

adb root
adb shell "date `date +%m%d%H%M%Y.%S`"

Comment: I believe you need to use `date -s` to set the date

Comment: When i use date -s its shows unknown option.

Comment: This is sample command with values : adb shell date  $(date +%11%11%11%11%2017).  It changes the date but for fraction of sec, i want to set it to my emulator and use it but i dint find any solution till now.